# Use "while" to check if there is a blank line C

Tags: c, while-loop, gets, puts

The code is to check if there is a blank line. I thought when I enter some text, it will keep doing the printf(), because it is stuck in the loop. But in fact, it just does the printf() once, and waits for another line of text. Why? Is it because the input will be wiped after the gets() function?

Here is the code

```
int main(){
    char input[257];
    char *ptr;

    puts("Enter text a line at a time, then press Enter");
    puts("Enter a blank line when done");

    while( *(ptr= gets(input)) != NULL){
        printf("You've entered: %s\n", input);
    }
    puts("Thank you and goodbye\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It runs the condition, then if it's true runs the body and the condition again, then if it's true runs the body and the condition again, then ...

Comment: if I enter some text won't it be saved in the input[]?? if it is saved in the input, the condition should always be true,  isn't it?

Comment: say, if I enter: hello world, I think the outcome will be: you've entered: hello world   you've entered hello world....(and it will keep doing that)

Comment: gets overwrite your `input` every time, so the condition is false if you enter blank line.

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman thx, I understand.  if gets rewrite the input, it will all make sense.

Comment: FYI. manual page of gets says this in BUGS section Never  use  gets().   Because  it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read,...... do read

Comment: `*(ptr= gets(input)) != NULL` should be `*(ptr= gets(input)) != 0` because the type of `*(ptr= gets(input))` is `char` and not `char*`. Apart from that your program works correctly because `*(ptr= gets(input)) != 0` is evaluated each time at the beginning of your while loop.

Comment: `gets` is unsafe as it can easily overrun the input buffer. Instead of `gets(input)` use `fgets(input, 257, stdin)` or `fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)`. (The form with `sizeof(input)` should only be used if `input` is an array, not a pointer.)

Comment: ...and if you use `fgets` then compare with `'\n'` as `fgets` stores the newline character, `gets` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this while should do the trick

```
while( (ptr= gets(input)) != NULL && input[0]!='\0')
```